# What does serialize actually do?

Tags: php

I have read that serialize Generates a storable representation of a value  but what does that mean?

What is "storable representation" here?

Can anyone provide explanation on this with an example?

Comment: What stopped you from running the [example in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/serialize) or simply doing [`echo serialize('foo');`](http://codepad.org/3Qk0tq7d)

Answer (score 12):

It produces a string representation of the variable.

Example:

```
$var = array(
    'product1' => array('color' => 'red', 'size' => 'L'),
    'product2' => array('color' => 'blue', 'size' => 'M')
);
echo serialize($var);
```

Output:

```
a:2:{s:8:"product1";a:2:{s:5:"color";s:3:"red";s:4:"size";s:1:"L";}s:8:"product2";a:2:{s:5:"color";s:4:"blue";s:4:"size";s:1:"M";}}
```

This string can be turned back into the original multidimensional array with `unserialize`.

Answer (score 2):

It means it is where the object/reference can be saved easily to a file, streamed, etc. then later reconstructed with the same data.

Say I have a class called `Person`. I'll do pseudo-C# for sake of simplicity.

```
class Person {
   string FirstName { get; set; }
   string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following `Person`.

```
var bob = new Person();
bob.FirstName = "Bob";
bob.LastName = "Smith";
```

Then if I serialize this as XML, I get.

```
<Person>
<FirstName>Bob</FirstName>
<LastName>Smith</LastName>
</Person>
```

At some later point, I can recreate an instance of `Person` that is equivalent to `bob`.

Answer (score 1):

### Take a look at:

1. [Serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)
2. [Comparison of data serialization formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats)